# spring integration: how to aggregate all new email messages and count it

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration

I'm working on an application that receive email weekly from an IMAP server and generate statistics about that. One of those is the amount of email with the same subject.

I was thinking to use a resequencer to store all messages from server and generate statistics just when all new message has been received and send messages individually finally.

But I miss both `sequence_number` and `correlation_id` and I can't find a proper way to release group when messages are over on the server.

This is my `integration-context.xml` :

```
<int:channel id="startMailSync"/>
<int:control-bus id="start" input-channel="startMailSync"/>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel" datatype="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage" />
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="mailClient"
    channel="receiveChannel" 
    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
    store-uri="imaps://[user]:[password]@mail.it/INBOX"
    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
    should-delete-messages="false"
    mail-filter-expression="from[0].address matches 'sender@sender.it'"
    auto-startup="false">

    <int:poller trigger="runOnceTrigger" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>

<int:resequencer 
    input-channel="receiveChannel" 
    output-channel="a"
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an aggregator not a resequencer; you can use a custom correlation strategy/expression (e.g. correlate on the subject) and a custom release strategy/expression.